# "for all" in datalog

Tags: declarative, datalog

Given a set of facts of the form `is_member(country, organisation)`, I have the following query to write in datalog:

> Return all countries who belong to all of the organisations of which Denmark is a member of.

I want to do something like

`member_all_Denmarks_organisations(Country):- 
    ¬( is_member('Denmark', Organization),
       ¬is_member(Country, Organization) 
     ).`

In other words, 'for every organization that Denmark is member of, Country is a member of it too'. But **datalog does not allow negated predicates which contain non-instantiated variables**, so this doesn't work.

How can I proceed? And in general, when wanting to express a 'for all' statement, how to do so in datalog?

Answer (score 0):

We are going to take the following alternative equivalent definition:

> Return all countries who not fail to belong to some organisation that Denmark is a member of.

Of course, you can only express this in a dialect of Datalog with negation. 
The following should do:

```
organisation_of_denmark(org) :- is_member('Denmark', org).

// a country c is disqualified if there is some organisation org 
// of which Denmark is a member but c isn't  
disqualified_country(c) :- organisation_of_denmark(org), country(c), ¬is_member(c, org). 

// we are only interested in countries that are not excluded by the previous rule
mmember_all_Denmarks_organisations(c) :- country(c), ¬disqualified_country(c). 

// in case there is no unary predicate identifying all countries 
// the best we can do is the following (knowing well that then the above 
// will only work for countries that are members of at least one organisation)
country(c) :- is_member(c, _).
```

This is precisely what you wrote also, only with intermediate relations included that 
capture some of your sub-formulas and with the atom `country(c)` included to act as 
a guard or a domain for the outer-most complementation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a case of expressing the following proposition P in Datalog:

`P(x) := for all y, p(y) => q(x,y)`

In Datalog, given database DB with, say, 2 columns and x in 1st column, this can be expressed as:

```
P(x):- DB(x,_), ¬disqualified(x).
disqualified(x):- DB(x,_), p(y), ¬q(x,y).
```

The trick is to create your own `disqualified()` predicate.
`DB(x,_)` is there just to instantiate `x` before it appears in a negated predicate.

---

In the specific Denmark case:

P(x) =: 'x is member of all Denmark's organisations'

p(y) =: `is_member('Denmark', y)`

q(x,y) =: `is_member(x,y)`

DB =: `is_member()`